# Creating like button for multiple items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am new to React and trying to learn more by creating projects. I made an API call to display some images to the page and I would like to create a like button/icon for each image that changes to red when clicked. However, when I click one button all of the icons change to red. I believe this may be related to the way I have set up my state, but can't seem to figure out how to target each item individually. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
`
 //store api data
 const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState([]);

 //state for like button
 const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 axios({
  url: "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events",
  params: {
    city: userInput,
    countryCode: "ca",
  },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    setEventsData(response.data._embedded.events);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
});

//here i've tried to filter and target each item and when i 
console.log(event) it does render the clicked item, however all the icons 
change to red at the same time
  const handleLikeEvent = (id) => {
   eventsData.filter((event) => {
     if (event.id === id) {
       setIsLiked(!isLiked);
     }
    });
  };

return (
   {eventsData.map((event) => {
        return (
          <div key={event.id}>
              <img src={event.images[0].url} alt={event.name}></img>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                 icon={faHeart}
                 className={isLiked ? "redIcon" : "regularIcon"}
                 onClick={() => handleLikeEvent(event.id)}
               />
          </div>
)

  `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store likes as array of ids

```
const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState([]);
const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);

const handleLikeEvent = (id) => {
  setLikes(likes.concat(id));
};

return (
  <>
    {eventsData.map((event) => {
      return (
        <div key={event.id}>
          <img src={event.images[0].url} alt={event.name}></img>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faHeart}
            className={likes.includes(event.id) ? "redIcon" : "regularIcon"}
            onClick={() => handleLikeEvent(event.id)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

Comment: This works, thank you for this. I do have to look into .concat and .includes though to understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your state, isLiked is just a boolean true or false, it has no way to tell the difference between button 1, or button 2 and so on, so you need a way to change the css property for an individual button, you can find one such implementation by looking Siva's answer, where you store their ids in an array